# Objective-C, Comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false, error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I'm getting the following warning `Comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false`.

I'm not sure how to fix it ?

```
if(topWindowIndex < 0)
```

It's defined as...

```
NSUInteger topWindowIndex = [allWindows count] - 1;
```

Comment: @halfdan Thanks for the edit, but bear in mind that pseudo-tags in question titles should be used organically. See [HOWTO: Writing Good Titles on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles).

Comment: @Bavarious, thanks for the note and the link, I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `[allWindows count] - 1` can never be negative, the test (and the code it controls) is unnecessary. If it can be negative, you should declare `topWindowIndex` as a signed type (`int` or `NSInteger`).

A better solution, IMO, is to store the count directly and use that instead:

```
NSUInteger numWindows = [allWindows count];
...
if (numWindows < 1) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is dangerous

```
NSUInteger topWindowIndex = [allWindows count] - 1;
```

if `[allWindows count]` is ever 0, you'll get a very large number (nonsense) as topWindowIndex.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic answer from above answers:**

Use `NSInteger` instead of `NSUInteger` (unsigned).